# kohana how to handle exceptions

Tags: exception, kohana, try-catch

I have a question about kohana exceptions.

I have a site that I want to put in production, and I don't want the exceptions to be simply thrown (like they are now), but I want to redirect the user to another page in case of an exception occured.

I use kohana 3, and I wonder: how can I catch an exception and redirect the user to another page if an exception happens:

example of code:

instead of

```
          if ( ! $sale->loaded())
    { 
        throw new Kohana_Request_Exception('Sale not found.');
    }
```

I want: something like: page not found.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do is register your own exception handler.

Take a look at the **[Error Handling documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/errors#http-exception-handling)** for an idea on what to do.  Basically, you can capture any type of exception you want and do something specific with it (such as display a 404 page).

Comment: I forgot to mention this.  The current example shown on that page has a couple bugs that will cause it to fail in the most recent version of Kohana. I've submitted a bug report and pull request on it, but until its resolved you'll have to make sure you fix the errors.  Check out **https://github.com/kohana/core/pull/94**